# Avoid lock on Remote Desktop Session when I lock my own machine

Tags: remote-desktop

I am working at Computer A and starting a non-fullscreen Microsoft RDP session to computer B (both Windows 10 Pro). When I take a break I press Win+L on Computer A and lock my session. When I return I need to log back into both machines: The Lock gets forwarded to computer B. This also happens when:

- I target another application on Computer A before locking
- I lock using the Start Menu -> Profile icon -> Lock Session, not the key combination
- When I use Devolution's Remote Desktop Manager (where I can access a lot more options)

It doesn't happen when:

- I don't lock Computer A when taking a break (that is: It's not a timeout thing)

I was wondering if there was a way to avoid this Lock to be forwarded. Regardless of whether I SHOULD, I am not looking for WHY Windows does this (but you are free, of course, to still explain, it's the Internet, I can't stop you :) )

Comment: @Tetsujin That's literally the first case I mention in my "this also happens when" list. So: Yes.

Comment: Does it happen even if you lock Computer A and login right after? Or must take some time?

Comment: @Ronaldo it happens immediately.

Answer (score 2):

One way to stop this behaviour is to disable the lock option of computer B. Won't avoid the lock to be forwarded, but it will not take effect on the remote computer. If it fits for you, here's how it's done:

Run `regedit` and navigate to the following key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` (if you don't have the **System** key, right click and create it).

When in the **System** key, on the right side of the window, `right click > new > DWORD` and name it **DisableLockWorkstation**.

Now right click **DisableLockWorkstation** and change the Value Data to 1. You're done!
You might need to restart the computer once before it works (although mine didn't need to).

Font: [How to Disable the Lock Screen Shortcut Key (Win + L) in Windows](https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-lock-screen-shortcut-key-windows/)

Comment: Unfortunately I still need the lock feature on computer B (it's my work laptop and I regularly need to lug it around for meetings and such, I just RDP to it from my desktop when at home). It's also managed by my work's domain, so I probably won't be able or allowed to change it.

Comment: I see. @VincentVancalbergh, I just noticed that when I chose to **show options** on the RDP connection window where you enter your credentials there's the tab **local resources** in which you have some keyboard options. Have you tried to change these settings?

Comment: One more thing: you mentioned the laptop is managed by the work's domain, maybe that's a domain config since I also RDP my computer at work and the remote connection doesn't lock when I lock my local computer. Could you contact your domain admin to check it?