# How to connect only video output of a video player to TV connected to HP Laptop via HDMI while use Laptop remotely for other purpose also?

Tags: laptop, video, remote-desktop, hdmi, tv

I have my personal HP laptop connected to TV via HDMI. And there is no issue to see display of my Laptop on TV alone or extend to both or whatever.

But while my family watching some stuff I would like to use this Laptop via `mstsc` to do my personal work. So I was looking some way to redirect the video output of players like VLC or players in websites to this TV while I'm using this laptop via `mstsc`.

But currently when I'm accessing it via `mstsc` from my other Laptop then as as expected TV screen get's locked. So currently this beast Laptop has no use for me but just playing dumb stuff all the day.

Both Laptop which is connected to TV (for which I'm looking a solution) and the one from which I want to access has Windows 10 Pro and Windows 10 Enterprise OS.

I tried to look for similar things on forums but couldn't find so far a clear solution for this problem.

I would be thankful for your answers.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but they make all kinds of cheap devices for this purpose. Roku, Apple TV, Google, Firestick, etc.

Comment: Yeah. I know that most of the time I'm working on my office laptop. But sometime I want to use my personal PC connected to TV just running YouTube on Chrome. I know that if I can get this device then I can cast things on TV via YouTube. But I was wondering if there is some way to direct/cast video on HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Remote Desktop will always lock the remote machine ([as expected](https://superuser.com/a/1352090/404503)). I have a similar setup that serves content and games. If I want to work on it while someone is using it, I use an alternate free solution that requires no remote confirmation (like VNC or TeamViewer). If the target PC never leaves your home and is only for entertainment, you may try [DisableLockWorkstation](https://superuser.com/a/1474492/404503).

Comment: But VNC or this DisableLockWorkstation technique they all take over what is running on the Windows Desktop. So if i minimize the App which is playing Video content then it will stop displaying on the TV also which is connected via HDMI.
I think there is no such App which can display Video output on certain HDMI port.

Comment: It does sound like you need another device involved. Get an Android stick of some sort.

Comment: Yeah looks like no other way. I'm thinking to buy Chrome Cast, as it does exactly the job I'm looking for. Since now users are getting more wireless, so I think there will never be such software implementation. Anyway thanks for you answer.